# JHipster microservices

Tags: java, gradle, микросервисы

Разбирасюь с JHipster.

Не могу найти примеры, поэтому вопрос.

Можно ли создать JHipster на базе микросервисов в виде одного проекта?

Большинство примеров ввида
https://github.com/viniciusboson/jhipster-microservice-example, т.е каждый микросервис - это отдельный проект.

Я бы хотел вида:

```
.git
microservice1
microservice2
gateway
...
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: вы имеете ввиду многомодульный maven/gradle  проект? как понимать в виде одного проекта?

Comment: да, все верно, многомодульный gradle